# Parse JSON without using array name

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm using GSON for parsing. I'm able to parse json using arrayName but I don't want to use arrayName as it is not static.arrayName can be change and more will be added from server. Please suggest.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "cityCode": "",
    "list": {
        "one": [
            {
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "adults": 2
            }
        ],
        "three": [
            {
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "adults": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Json is very bad. You should Json 1st according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your case.
Remember that JSONObject has keys() method which list all its attributes. And you can see that, Iterator result is un-ordered, run this code and see result.

```
static void parseJson(String json){
    try{
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

        //Get "list" JSONObject
        JSONObject obj = object.getJSONObject("list");
        //Try to get all attributes of that object
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<String> iterator = obj.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray(key);
            int size = arr.length();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                JSONObject o = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("JSON", "=> "+o.getInt("adults"));
            }
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I'm using Gson so how can be done using json pojo

Answer (score 0):

Your Json should look like following.

```
{
    "cityCode": "",
    "list":[
            {
                "index":"one"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"one"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"one"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"three"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"three"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"three"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"three"
                "adults": 2
            },
            {
                "index":"three"
                "adults": 2
            }
        ]
}
```

Share you server side code.

Comment: I agrree with u but I cannot change json format so is there any possibilities to parse it wihtout using array Name

Comment: Not Possible without  changing format. because you are not sure about total number of static indexes.